# PDFToolKit is sending weird data

Tags: node.js, stream, node-pdfkit

I have installed [PDFKit](http://npmjs.com/package/pdfkit) for node.js. When i call my method to download a PDF file, i get this kind of characers on my browser:

```
xœU»nÜ0ìùüËûâ’Œ+8Ò¹.H‘œOn|EàÂ¿ï!ï>  AÔ’”†ÃåÌŠ#áºa4Î§ð+ðÕØ‡ýe£ªMfç)av
```

This is my code:

```
var doc = new PDFDocument({ layout: 'landscape' });
doc.pipe(res);
doc.moveDown(1);
doc.text(reportName, { align: "center" });
doc.text(bNames.join(','), { align: "center" });
doc.text(dateFrom + " - " + dateTo, { align: "center" });
doc.moveDown(2);
const table0 = {
   headers: allNames,
   rows: allData
};
doc.table(table0, {
   prepareHeader: () => doc.font('Helvetica-Bold').fontSize(10),
   prepareRow: (row, i) => doc.font('Helvetica').fontSize(10)
});
doc.end();
```

Is there something else i have to tell PDFKit to work right?

EDIT1:

I am running this code on my backend and sending it to my frontend so i can download it there

Comment: Yes there is --- "In addition to PDFKit, you'll need somewhere to stream the output to. HTML5 has a Blob object which can be used to store binary data, and get URLs to this data in order to display PDF output inside an iframe, or upload to a server, etc. In order to get a Blob from the output of PDFKit, you can use the blob-stream module."

Comment: Isnt this line: doc.pipe(res); doing that?

Comment: try `res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf')` before it

Comment: additionally,  maybe `res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename="test.pdf"')`

Comment: This: `res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf')` did the trick. Can you set it as an answer to mark it as answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a PDF response straight to the browser, you need to add the header so it understands the binary data.

Set this before the response is piped.

```
res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf')
```